# Standard practice on calling Javascript from MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty experienced with Web Forms, but attempting a site in MVC to broaden my skill set. In Web Forms, you could do something like this to execute some JavaScript when the page loads:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "unique-script-id", "alert('Data saved.');", true);
```

What is the equivalent way to do this from a Controller? Should I pass a JavaScript block in the ViewBag, then in my View check for the existence of that script and render it? Or should I abandon the idea of doing this from my controllers and instead use AJAX from the client side to post the form to a Web API, and then based on the HTTP status code display the appropriate message?

```
public ActionResult Submit(ArticleModel article)
{
    //save model to database

    //I think here I want to do the MVC equivalent of registering a startup script providing a success message.

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: typically the javascript is handled in the view:
<script src="~/path/to/script.js"></script>

no need to register like with webforms.

Comment: @mrpotocnik Yes, I'm aware of how to place a script in a view, that's no different from Web Forms. However, my question isn't about how to define the JavaScript, it's how to execute it from a controller in response to certain actions when developing an MVC application.

Comment: Re-read your question... It seems to me it would be more appropriate to use ajax.

Comment: Or just send a string to the view and render it in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @SLaks Is there a reason that one might do that instead of AJAX?

Comment: @mrpotocnik Why not just pass the script as a string to the view from the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the equivalent way to do this from a Controller?

You don't.  Not from the controller anyway.

JavaScript is part of the view.  The controller provides a model to the view, nothing more.  It shouldn't be coupled to the view in any way.  Your JavaScript would be invoked within the view.

If you're looking to *conditionally include* JavaScript in the view, you can wrap it in a conditional check on a model property:

```
@if(Model.SomeBooleanProperty)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // your script here
    </script>
}
```

Then the model would be logically determining whether or not that functionality is invoked.  The view is simply binding to the properties on the model.

**Edit:** Another approach, structurally similar but without adding a property to a model, is to use something like `ViewBag`.  In your controller you'd set the value:

```
ViewBag.SomeBooleanProperty = true;
```

Then you'd check it in the view:

```
@if(ViewBag.SomeBooleanProperty)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // your script here
    </script>
}
```

Keep in mind, however, that this introduces *some* coupling between the controller and the view.  The view now *assumes* that something other than the model has been set.  It then becomes the responsibility of *any code which returns that view* to explicitly set that value.  Models are a way to enforce this more explicitly, eliminating the coupling.

Additionally, you seem to be misunderstanding something in one of your comments:

> This information I'm talking about isn't data, so it doesn't belong in the model.

Models don't contain *just data*.  Models contain the core business logic of your application.  *Just data* results in "anemic models."

Comment: This data however is not tied to the model, it's for things such as confirmations like "Your data has been successfully saved.". It doesn't make sense to me to include that in the model.

Comment: @mason: Then where are you determining this condition?  How is the controller involved at all?  If the view is changing in response to some server-side state then I can think of no better place to include that logic than in the model.

Comment: The controller is processing incoming requests and executing application specific logic, [according to MSFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410269%28VS.98%29.aspx). This information I'm talking about isn't data, so it doesn't belong in the model. It's logic that I'm executing in response to whether an action completed successfully or not. So I believe this should happen in the controller, the question is whether or not the controller should directly execute the JavaScript or whether that should happen on the client side (as part of a form submit) or as part of an AJAX request.

Comment: @mason: If you insist on keeping this off the model and you can use something like `ViewBag` (I'll update the answer accordingly).  It may just come down to a matter of personal preference, the functionality is nearly identical.  Personally I'd prefer to create logical view models than to just stuff values into `ViewBag`.  Either way, the principle is the same... The *controller* doesn't *invoke* client-side logic.  The view manages client-side logic, and simply binds to the model (or off-model properties in `ViewBag` if you really want).

Comment: I thought about your answer from the context of a View Model. So let's say I have a function on my model that validates the model, and returns ValidationEventArgs, this might contain a general "Passed Validation" or "Failed Validation" boolean, along with specific validation errors. Should I pass the ValidationEventArgs to the view as a View Model, and then in the view call the appropriate JavaScript to display the validation errors (or success message)?

Comment: @mason: You certainly can do that.  If you are providing to the view a model which is in some way invalid and the view needs to display information about that invalid state then clearly the model would need to provide the information about that invalid state to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Learning the "MVC Way" of doing things will help you in the long run to develop more modular, testable applications.

In your example, you are wrapping your functionality around multiple components.  You are wanting your controller to tell your view to perform some action.  This is the practice that MVC frameworks in general strive to deviate from.

MVC frameworks, including ASP.NET MVC, adhere to the principal of least responsibility.

The job of your controller is to Control your application flow.  It isn't even really responsible for program logic, you will likely have Services to handle things like Database management, complex calculation, etc.  Your controller shouldn't really care about the view, or how the view displays information; it should only care how to make a view and tell the view to do it's thing.  Typically, controllers can be slimmed down to less than 10 lines of code in all but extremely complex scenarios.

By the same token, the view shouldn't care how the controller works, or the services that the controller responds to.  Views should never be told how to display information, errors, etc, only given data or a status to work with.

Keeping this separation of concerns means a few things.  First, it ensures that you can make changes to one part of the application without it having a major impact on another portion.  Secondly, you can test if the controller is working without ever having a view, and you can render the view with sample information without a functional controller.  This makes your development team much more efficient.

Bottom line, you should keep the idea of Separation of Concerns in the front of your mind when working with MVC, and if you are ever thinking that you need to have your controller tell the view to show something, you are probably going the wrong direction with your overall architecture.

Comment: +1 Thank you for the clarification, in addition to David's comments this helped me determine the correct way to go. I know about Separation of Concerns, just needed a reminder and some specific direction in how to apply that principle in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm..
You can directly use javaScript in CSHTML and if you want to show your script under condition than you can bind it inside if condition just pass a signal from controller to show your script only
`true` or `false`
**EXAMPLE**
set a boolean value from controller and keep in ViewBag

```
ViewBag.isSubmit= true;
```

and then check condition in your view

```
@if ((bool)ViewBag.isSubmit==true)
{
    <script>  
          alert('Submit Successfully');  
    </script>
}
```

but remember to insert @ before `if` because this is CSHTML and uses Razor syntax.

Comment: David already provided this suggestion...3 years ago. What does your answer bring to the table that's new?

Comment: yup another solution if you wanna execute your script directly from action you can do like this    
`Response.Write("<script>alert('Submit Successfully');</script>");`

Comment: it will execute your script directly from action not from view

Comment: That's a terrible idea. If you do Response.Write, then you have no control where in the markup your additions end up. It also violates separation of concerns.

Comment: @mason you can make an ajax call and get Response.StatusCode for Either successfully submitted or not and on the behalf of status code you can take any decision